# On change Select - get data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey what I need that when user change option:

for example if the user select the second option it must return by 2 ..etc.

**My code below:**

```js
  $('.selectContainer').on('change', function () {
        var index =            $(this).find('.selectCar').data('index');
        alert(index);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select class="selectContainer">
        <option class="selectCar" data-index="1">
            one
        </option>
        <option class="selectCar" data-index="2">
            two
        </option>
        <option class="selectCar" data-index="3">
            three
        </option>
        <option class="selectCar" data-index="4">
            four
        </option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this).find('option:selected').data('index');`

```js
$('.selectContainer').on('change', function() {
  var index = $(this).find('option:selected').data('index');
  alert(index);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectContainer">
        <option class="selectCar" data-index="1">
            one
        </option>
        <option class="selectCar" data-index="2">
            two
        </option>
        <option class="selectCar" data-index="3">
            three
        </option>
        <option class="selectCar" data-index="4">
            four
        </option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.selectContainer').on('change', function () {
        var index =            $(this).find('.selectCar:selected').data('index');
        alert(index);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select class="selectContainer">
        <option class="selectCar" data-index="1">
            one
        </option>
        <option class="selectCar" data-index="2">
            two
        </option>
        <option class="selectCar" data-index="3">
            three
        </option>
        <option class="selectCar" data-index="4">
            four
        </option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Update your jQuery code like as -

```
$('.selectContainer').change(function () {
    var index = $(this).find('.selectCar:selected').data('index');
    console.log(index);
});
```